# grails: how to change compiled GSPs (gsp*.class files)?

Tags: grails, weblogic, gsp

I'm using grails in weblogic and need to change a class file in a exploded deploy folder.
But this class is actually a gsp compiled file.

So, the question is: where GSP files (.class) stay in a war ?

Note: I'm using external GSPs, setting `grails.gsp.view.dir` in Config.groovy file.

Answer (score 6):

Since Grails 1.3.5, you just have to set `grails.gsp.enable.reload = true` in `Config.groovy` or set a system property `-Dgrails.gsp.enable.reload=true` to the appserver (tomcat, etc.) startup.

GSP reloading in WAR deployment mode has been broken for Grails `2.0M1` and `M2` builds (`GRAILS-8189`). It's fixed in master branch and will be released in `2.0RC1`. GSP reloading for precompiled GSPs is only available for `1.3.5` - `1.3.7` in the `1.3.x` branch. For `1.2.x` there is no support.

The view files (GSP "source code" for precompiled GSP classes) are under `WEB-INF/grails-app/views` directory in the exploded deployment directory. Changes get picked up within 10 seconds (check interval is 5 seconds by default).

If you have `grails.gsp.view.dir` set, then the files should be under that directory (manual has more instructions). Reloading only works if you also have `grails.gsp.enable.reload` set. There has to be a trailing slash in the `grails.gsp.view.dir` property.

There is more information in the manual:
[Grails Reference Documentation - 6.2.6 Making Changes to a Deployed Application](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.6%20Making%20Changes%20to%20a%20Deployed%20Application):