# Is it possible to allow editing of GSPs (including layouts) as part of the functionality of a Grails application?

Tags: grails, content-management-system, gsp

I am working on a Grails site which although it needs to include a deal of CMS-like functionality is yet not (for various reasons) being built as part of an actual CMS installation. One thing that I need to allow the user to do is to edit the HTML layout — which, in a Grails application, is laid out in a GSP file — and other normally-static elements of the different pages, which will neither be tied to any specific domain object nor form any part of one of the CRUD pages which deal with domain objects.

I know both that [it is possible to specify the views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840439/grails-how-to-change-compiled-gsps-gsp-class-files) and that it is possible to write, from within the app somewhere, to actual files in the running app. I know further that it might require a great enormous deal of care, if I were to do this, to be sure that the user does not too badly destroy the entire layout and content of the page, and I am prepared to deal with that. But is it possible to allow user editing of the layouts and other GSP files used to create a Grails page? If so, how might I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store the template/layout in the database (as some have suggested above) you can 
render it using the GroovyPagesTemplateEngine:

```
package com.mycompany

import groovy.text.Template;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine 

class TemplatingService {
  GroovyPagesTemplateEngine groovyPagesTemplateEngine

  def render(String templateString, Map model) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(templateString.getBytes());
    Template template = groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(bais)

    try {
      def writer = new StringWriter()
      template.make(model).writeTo(writer)
      return writer.toString()
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle exception
      return ""    // or "[an error occurred]" or rethrow the exception
    }
  }
}
```

Now, while you **CAN** do this, please be sure to think of the implications.  Anything you could execute in a gsp can be executed in this context.  Like writing to, or deleting files, executing commands, etc.

I never figured out how to leverage a SecurityManager to limit what could be done in the templates, so my solution was to not allow users to enter templates into the database.  If I want a new template, I put it there myself, after checking it for security implications.

You can also improve performance by caching the results of `createTemplate()` to avoid recompiling it each time.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to store chunks of HTML in the database as domain objects. Your views could then automatically pull in the html. A simple interface could be created to allow the users to edit the html. For more discussion on this see [this thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Ideas-needed-for-quick-Grails-page-updates-td3313708.html) Another possible option would be to use the [Weceem plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/weceem)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of integrating cms like functionality into a Grails application, while possible, I've seen different approaches.

One way is to have a CMS aside and ensure that it is able to :

- read gsp after a transformation process, usually an automated or scheduled job
- produce gsp files consumed by the Grails application. In this case as you mentioned you can override the views location.

To avoid serious UI issues or CMS limitations with the approach that I am describing, you would not use layouts. The CMS vendor provides modules to import/export GSP files, if not you write that layer yourself.

Hope it helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A layout is also a gsp view, which by definition is responsible for dealing with dynamic view contents.

But, it is not a good practice to edit gsp files directly and compile them in the run-time.

Instead, you can define a Domain class where customized contents were persisted and load from a pre-defined gsp layout.

Specifically, you can define something like following domain classes to save custom web elements:

```
class Module {
    Integer positionLeft
    Integer positionTop
    Integer width
    Integer height
    String  className   //CSS class
    String  border      
    String  borderColor 
    Integer borderSize  
    Integer seq
    String  content
    String  type
    static  hasMany = [components: Component]        //inner elements within a module
    Module  parentModule                    //support nested module structure to ensure flexibility
    User    owner
}

class Component {
    String title
    String content
    String methodName
    String url
    String type     //I-image，A-attachment，L-external link，T-text，G-graph report，D-data table，R RSS FEED...
    String font
    String fontFamily
    String fontBold
    String fontUnderline
    String color    
    String textAlign
    String source      //uri -- enables ajax call to some method to get dynamic data
    Integer seq
}
```

With client-side javascript, the app could easily enable users to generate the customized view by drag, resize, select different element types from some menus, and submit to backend controllers who perform CRUD operation of these elements.

Then in the layout, render those customized elements one by one:

```
<%@ page import="com.app.Module" %>
<g:each in="${Module.findAllByOwnerAndParentModuleIsNull(session.user,[fetch:[components:'join']]).collect {[
            id:it.id,
            posLeft:it.posLeft,
            posTop:it. posTop,
            width:it.width,
            height:it.height,
            className:it.className,
            border:it.border,
            borderColor:it.borderColor,
            borderSize:it.borderSize,
            seq:it.seq,
            content:it.content,
            type:it.type,
            components:it.components,
            innerModules:Module.findAllByParentModule(it)
        ]}}" var="module" status="i">
    <div class="${module.className?module.className:''}" style="position: absolute; left: ${module.posLeft}px; top: ${module.posTop}px; width: ${module.width}px; height: ${module.height}px; border: ${module.borderColor} ${module.borderSize?(module.borderSize+'px'):''} ${module.border};">
        <g:each in="${module.innerModules}" var="inner">  
             <div class="${inner.className?inner.className:''}"  style="position: absolute; left: ${inner.posLeft-module.posLeft}px; top: ${inner.posTop-module.posTop}px; width: ${inner.width}px; height: ${inner.height}px; border: blue 1px solid;">
                  <g:render template="/home/module" model="[
                      module: inner
                  ]"/>
            </div>
        </g:each> 
        <g:render template="/home/module" model="[
             module: module
        ]"/>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

In this way, each user could manage its personalized layout.

Answer (score 1):

A proper way to render GSP files under Grails is to use the Grails' GSP bean. With this, you can access *all* tag libs functionalities. The following is a snippet in my Grails plugin that processes GSP files:

```
GroovyPagesTemplateEngine gsp = (GroovyPagesTemplateEngine)appCtx.getBean(GROOVY_PAGES_TEMPLATE_ENGINE);
Template template = gsp.createTemplate(new ByteArrayResource(bufferStr.getBytes(encoding)), false);
Writable w = template.make();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
w.writeTo(new PrintWriter(sw));
```